# How to enable TLS1.2 for port 1433

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server, tls-1.2

I have received vulnerability on Microsoft SQL server 2008 (RTM)

> [high] [1433/tcp/mssql] TLS Version 1.2 Protocol Not Enabled
>   TLS v1.2 is not enabled on this port.

Already enabled TLS 1.2 on OS level (Windows Server 2008 R2).

below are the details Product version:
Microsoft SQL server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22(x64) 
Product level: RTM Product Edition : Express edition(64bit) 
Whether I need to go for SQL Server 2008 SP4 10.0.6547.0(First build supports TLS 1.2)

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is this KB article, which lists the required updates you need to install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244 , which also lists which updates are needed on the **client** machines trying to connect to a TLS 1.2 enabled SQL Server.

Also, read http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/tls-1-2-support-read-first/ , which lists known problems and caveats. It states

> It seems straightforward, but as of today, not all builds will enable you to rush out and convert to TLS 1.2 exclusively

Comment: Agreed. Upgrading is more trouble than it's worth considering there are no known vulnerabilities in TLS 1.1 so it's a wonder why it's flagged on an audit. Probably worth fighting over. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57878/tls-v-1-1-vulnerabilities

Comment: Thanks for update, I have verified sql server service(its 2008 and not 2012), below are the details
Product version: Microsoft SQL server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22(x64)
Product level: RTM
Product Edition : Express edition(64bit)

Whether I need to go for SQL Server 2008 SP4 10.0.6547.0(First build supports TLS 1.2)

Comment: Team
Can you please suggest on this